# Disk Utility reports 'invalid internal_flags' on Mac APFS drive

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, apfs

Why doesn't Apple address the 'invalid internal_flags' warning that shows up after running Disk Utility? Disk Utility doesn't fix the issue, and when I called Apple, they pretty much brushed aside any concern I had about the warning; they kept saying everything was OK as long as I saw 'File system check exit code is 0.'

But I feel I have no choice except to be prudent and reformat my internal APFS. PITA, but I'd rather be safe than sorry. Does anyone know more about this issue? Is it so rare? If it really is a problem that affects a lot of users, how to get Apple to address it?

So I posed the question to https://chat.openai.com/chat:

**Are you familiar with a Mac Disk Utility warning similar to 'warning: inode_val: object (oid 0x39): invalid internal_flags (0x28000)'?**

Yes, I am familiar with the Mac Disk Utility warning message you mentioned. This warning indicates that there is a problem with the file system on the disk. Specifically, it suggests that there is an issue with an inode (a data structure that stores information about a file or directory) and that the "internal_flags" associated with that inode are invalid.
This warning can be caused by a number of factors, including disk errors, file system corruption, and software bugs. In some cases, the warning may indicate a serious problem that requires immediate attention, while in other cases it may be a benign error that can be safely ignored.
If you see this warning in Disk Utility, it is recommended that you back up your data immediately, and then run a file system repair tool such as Disk Utility's First Aid function. You can access First Aid by selecting your disk in Disk Utility, and then clicking on the "First Aid" button in the toolbar. If the repair tool is unable to fix the problem, you may need to consider reformatting the disk or seeking the assistance of a professional data recovery service.

**Your advice seems reasonable. I would like to point out that one gets the warning after running the Disk Utility First Aid function, and it doesn't disappear after re-running First Aid. In other words, it appears to be a warning about something, but it doesn't get repaired. Do you know exactly what that warning indicates?**

Thank you for the additional information. If you are receiving the warning message after running the Disk Utility First Aid function, it is possible that the file system on the disk is experiencing a more serious issue that cannot be repaired by Disk Utility.
The warning message indicates that there is an issue with an inode on the disk that has invalid internal flags. The internal flags are metadata that describe various attributes of the inode, such as whether it is a file or a directory, and whether it is read-only or writable. If these flags are invalid, it can indicate corruption or damage to the file system.
While it is not possible to say exactly what is causing the problem without further investigation, it is possible that there are additional errors or inconsistencies in the file system that are preventing the repair process from completing successfully. In some cases, the file system may be irreparably damaged and may need to be reformatted or replaced.
If you have important data on the disk, it is recommended that you back up your data immediately and seek the assistance of a professional data recovery service, as they may have additional tools and techniques to recover data from a damaged file system.

**I do appreciate your answer. Is it possible for me to paste the 53 lines of the Disk Utility report here, so that you could review them, and perhaps add information to your answer?**

Yes, you can certainly paste the contents of the Disk Utility report here. I would be happy to review them and provide additional information or guidance as needed.

**Verifying file system.
Volume could not be unmounted.
Using live mode.
Performing fsck_apfs -n -l -x /dev/rdisk1s1
Checking volume.
Checking the container superblock.
Checking the EFI jumpstart record.
Checking the space manager.
Checking the object map.
Checking the APFS volume superblock.
Checking the object map.
Checking the fsroot tree.
warning: inode_val: object (oid 0x4f44a61): invalid internal_flags (0x28000)
warning: inode_val: object (oid 0x50988d6): invalid internal_flags (0x28000)
warning: inode_val: object (oid 0x50988d7): invalid internal_flags (0x28000)
warning: inode_val: object (oid 0x50988d8): invalid internal_flags (0x28000)
warning: inode_val: object (oid 0x50988d9): invalid internal_flags (0x28000)
warning: inode_val: object (oid 0x50988da): invalid internal_flags (0x28000)
warning: inode_val: object (oid 0x50988dc): invalid internal_flags (0x28000)
warning: inode_val: object (oid 0x50988de): invalid internal_flags (0x28000)
warning: inode_val: object (oid 0x50988df): invalid internal_flags (0x28000)
warning: inode_val: object (oid 0x50988e0): invalid internal_flags (0x28000)
warning: inode_val: object (oid 0x50988e2): invalid internal_flags (0x28000)
warning: inode_val: object (oid 0x5098d5c): invalid internal_flags (0x28000)
warning: inode_val: object (oid 0x5098d5d): invalid internal_flags (0x28000)
warning: inode_val: object (oid 0x5098d5e): invalid internal_flags (0x28000)
warning: inode_val: object (oid 0x5098d5f): invalid internal_flags (0x28000)
warning: inode_val: object (oid 0x5098d60): invalid internal_flags (0x28000)
warning: inode_val: object (oid 0x5098d61): invalid internal_flags (0x28000)
warning: inode_val: object (oid 0x5098d62): invalid internal_flags (0x28000)
warning: inode_val: object (oid 0x5098d63): invalid internal_flags (0x28000)
warning: inode_val: object (oid 0x5098d64): invalid internal_flags (0x28000)
warning: inode_val: object (oid 0x5098d65): invalid internal_flags (0x28000)
warning: inode_val: object (oid 0x5098d66): invalid internal_flags (0x28000)
warning: inode_val: object (oid 0x5098d68): invalid internal_flags (0x28000)
warning: inode_val: object (oid 0x5098d91): invalid internal_flags (0x28000)
warning: inode_val: object (oid 0x5098d92): invalid internal_flags (0x28000)
warning: inode_val: object (oid 0x5098d93): invalid internal_flags (0x28000)
warning: inode_val: object (oid 0x5098d94): invalid internal_flags (0x28000)
warning: inode_val: object (oid 0x5098d95): invalid internal_flags (0x28000)
warning: inode_val: object (oid 0x5098d97): invalid internal_flags (0x28000)
warning: inode_val: object (oid 0x5098d99): invalid internal_flags (0x28000)
warning: inode_val: object (oid 0x5098d9a): invalid internal_flags (0x28000)
warning: inode_val: object (oid 0x5098d9b): invalid internal_flags (0x28000)
warning: inode_val: object (oid 0x5098d9d): invalid internal_flags (0x28000)
Checking the snapshot metadata tree.
Checking the extent ref tree.
Checking the snapshots.
Verifying allocated space.
The volume /dev/rdisk1s1 appears to be OK.
File system check exit code is 0.
Restoring the original state found as mounted.
Operation successful.**

Thank you for providing the Disk Utility report. As I suspected, the report indicates that there are a number of files or directories with invalid internal flags. The specific objects (inodes) that have been flagged as problematic are listed in the report, and they are identified by their object IDs (oids).
Based on this report, it seems that there are issues with the file system on the disk that have not been successfully repaired by the First Aid function. While the volume appears to be OK, the warnings suggest that there may be underlying issues with the file system that could lead to data loss or other problems.
At this point, I would recommend that you back up your data immediately and consider seeking the assistance of a professional data recovery service. A data recovery service may be able to provide additional tools and techniques to recover data from a damaged file system, or to repair the file system if possible. It is important to act quickly to minimize the risk of data loss, as continuing to use the disk in its current state could lead to further damage or corruption.

Comment: Was this drive ever exposed to a version of macOS that is newer than the macOS this Disk Utility came from?

Comment: (To clarify: the DU report is of my iMac's internal drive (APFS), running High Sierra.)

If such an exposure would include starting my iMac in Target Mode, and mounting it on a MBP (laptop) running Ventura, then the answer is yes. I did not run DU from Ventura on the mounted volume. 

The DU report shows multiple 'invalid internal_flags' warnings; before the Target Mode use (to see if backing up my iMac's drive could be done faster), I had previously seen only a single instance of the 'invalid internal_flags' warning after running DU.

Comment: So the answer to my question is "No".